# can a number be written as another number to its own power

Tags: elementary-number-theory, tetration

Do we know which numbers can be written as another number to its own power? More precisely, if we have a number $x$, when can we write it as $n^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

For example, if $q$ is a prime at least $5$ and $x= (q(q^2-1))^{q^2}$, can we write $x=n^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Intuition says that writing $n^n$ in its prime factorization, we have each of those primes divides the power by definition. Whereas with $x$, $q$ divides $q^2$ but $q^2-1$ does not divide it, does any of this make sense?

Comment: Clearly $q$ divides $x$ but $q^2$ does not, so $x$ can't be a perfect power.

Comment: Ohhh right, if $q^2$ divides $x$, we could write it as $q^k$ for some $k$ right? Without even considering $q$ and $k$ must be equal here.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  I know $q$ divides $x$ because you wrote it as an explicit factor.  I know $q^2$ does not divide $x$ because, clearly, $q$ does not divide $q^2-1$.

Comment: I meant is this why it cannot be a perfect power? I do understand that $q^2$ does not divide it.

Comment: Say $x=y^m$ for some integers $y,m$ with $m>1$.  Then $q\,|\,x\implies q\,|\,y\implies q^m\,|\,x$.

Comment: Yup, I see, thanks a lot.

Comment: I have gone back to this exercise and sort of got confused. I just cannot see if $q^2$ does not divide this number, why does that mean that it cannot be written as a perfect power? Like if $q^m$ divides it, it does not say much about $q^{m-1}$ say...

Comment: I posted something below.  There's probably a quicker way to see the contradiction, but I think that what I wrote gets the job done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to argue that the given $x$ can not be of the form $n^n$.

For any prime $p$ and a natural number $m$, let $v_p(m)$ denote the order to which $p$ divides $m$.  Thus $v_2(24)=3$ since $2^3\,|\,24$ but $2^4\,\nmid \,24$. for example.

Suppose that $q$ is a prime and that $$x=\left(q(q^2-1)\right)^{q^2}=n^n$$ for some natural number $n$.  We will derive a contradiction.

Since $q\,\nmid\,(q^2-1)$ we easily see that $v_q(x)=q^2$.  It is also easy to see that $v_q(n^n)=v_q(n)\times n$.

Let $v_q(n)=a$.  Then $n=q^am$ with $q\,\nmid\,m$.  And we see that $$q^2=v_q(x)=v_q(n^n)=a\times q^a\times m$$

But this is impossible.  It would imply that  $m=1$ since otherwise we'd have $m\,|\,q^2$ which is impossible for $m>1$ (as $m$ is prime to $q$ by construction.).  But if $m=1$ then $n=q^a$ which is impossible since $\gcd(q^2-1,n)>1$.  And we are done.

Answer (score 4):

By your definition, the list of numbers for which that can be done are
$$1^1, 2^2, 3^3, 4^4, 5^5, 6^6...$$

If you broaden it to include non integers, the answer becomes a little more interesting, as the graph of $x^x$ has a minimum at $(1/e, (1/e)^{1/e}) \approx (0.368,0.692)$, so any number $y$ higher than about $0.692$ can be written as $y = x^x$ for some $x$.